# How to know distance between places

Tags: iphone, core-location

Hello I am creating travel app. I want to find current location and find the distance between selected hotel or place from this location.. I searched core location but it is not returning longitude and latitude of current location in simulator .please help me and how can I calculate distance ?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate distances you can use the [`distanceFromLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) method of the CLLocation class.

Comment: You can't test this with your simulator as location manager fails in the simulator. You need to test this feature on the device. If you just need to know the accuracy of the distance, get the lat/long value of a particular point from google maps and hard code it in your application and test.